# how can we transpernt webview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, webview

i want to transparent web view hoc i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `opaque` and `backgroundColor` properties:

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Thank you v.much ...i want to know from where u got this ans ?

Comment: The first time I needed it, I found that UIWebView `opaque` property was set to YES. The doc for `opaque` says *You should always set the value of this property to NO if the view is fully or partially transparent.* so setting `backgroundColor` to clearColor was not sufficient in this case.

Comment: what mean by opeque ? i dont understand what the process behind this opaque ? ...what apple doing for transfer view ?

Comment: "opaque" means that nothing will be drawn behind the view. This improves performance during animations for example.